# Finding Green function and solution of Dirichlet problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations, greens-function, fundamental-solution

For unit open ball $D=\{{x}\in\mathbb{R}:\lvert{x}\rvert<1\}$, I need to find Green function $G$ with Dirichlet Problem
$$
\Delta u =0\,\, \text{ in }D,\qquad u=g\,\, \text{ on }\partial D
$$
Let $\Phi({x})=-\frac{1}{2\pi}\log\lvert{x}\rvert$ be fundamental solution of Laplacian at ${x}\neq{0}$ and $\phi^{x}$ be the solution of following Dirichlet problem
$$
\Delta \phi^{x} =0\,\, \text{ in }D,\qquad u(y)=\Phi(y-x)\,\, \text{ on }\partial D
$$
Note that $G(x,y)=\Phi(y-x)
-\phi^x (y)$.

My friend ask me this question, but I cannot understand the conditions because of abstruse terminology and my short study at partial differential equation.
Please, give me solution and make me understanding this problem.
Thank you for reading my question with my short English.

Comment: To solve this problem you need to find the Poisson kernel which is the normal derivative of the Green’s function. The derivation of the Green’s function in a ball can be found in many textbooks including, for example, “Partial Differential Equations” by Lawrence Evans

Comment: Also, $D$ is a subset of $\mathbb R$ but the fundamental solution you’ve quoted is for $\mathbb R^2$

Comment: It's my mistake. D is subset of R2